# Stored procedure user interaction

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a big stored procedure. 
It has multiple inserts into different tables. 
What I want to do is to pause stored procedure and ask user to confirm some stuff (Like do you like records that being inserted), if they click yes, I continue stored procedure and got to second table. It is Sql Server 2008 and asp.net front-end.
Thanks!

UPDATE:  I need around 100 pauses. no other way than creating 100 sp?

Comment: If you have 100 points where you need to stop and ask the user for confirmation of something, then the first thing you need is to redesign your process.  Nobody will want to sit there and click 100 times.

Comment: definitely, no user seat for 100 pause for confirmation. Can you elaborate more about your design process & what are you going to do with user interaction? what is the actual process you are trying? Provide much more details to get the best solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User interaction doesn't belong in the stored procedure (SP). It belongs in the user interface. You need to handle all of that separately - if need be, write multiple stored procedures. Your UI can then ask for input, run a procedure, get results (if needed), ask for more input (based on previous results, if needed), run another SP, etc., passing the user input into the SPs as parameters if it's needed by the SP.

EDIT: Think of what you're trying to do. A database server is designed to provide **data**, not the user interface. If you have multiple step procedures that require user input for those steps, you need to handle that in the user interface. The server can accept input through parameters that are passed from the user interface, and can provide results - that's it. Each step of that process should be independent, and the UI should control the flow through those steps. The database has no business knowing anything about the user interface; the user interface is exactly what it's called - the way to interact with the user.

Answer (score 0):

Then you need two stored procedures.
1. Call SP1
2. App interacts with users
3. Call SP2

Comment: Consider your SQL Server to be an object and the SPs to be methods on that object.  If you wanted half a method to execute, then control return to the caller, and the second half of the method to complete after some user interaction, how would you do it?  I'm afraid you need to refactor your code such that each SP (method) executes in it's entirety and then returns to the ASP.Net code.  So, requiring multiple SPs for the example you gave.

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your post to provide the information in your comment and then delete the comment. The comment provides some good information, and will improve your answer considerably. :)