# User Input during stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is it possible to take a user input during the time when the stored procedure runs? Like pause for a moment and ask for a user input and then continue?

There is a parameter @query inside my stored procedure and I want the option in which the user can modify the value of this parameter at a certain point of the procedure.

Possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think this is possible.

You might want to look at CLR Stored Procedures:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx

They allow the full .NET framework inside sprocs. But even then, I don't see how you could stop for user input.

Answer (score 2):

You basically should not expect SP to do this. The correct way of making use of SP is actually separate what you wanna do into multiple smaller SP and use your UI to control it.
You may wanna refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433411/stored-procedure-user-interaction)